# A good version control application

Tags: php, version-control, windows-7

What is the best version conrtol application? I'll setup it to my Windows 7. I have installed WAMP. So it could be eider Windows 7 application or PHP application. And my purpose is to manage / version-control PHP files only.

Comment: Please (1) add the tag "subjective", (2) mark this Community Wiki, and (3) rephrase it to ask specific questions about SCM systems as they relate to your need.

Comment: You forgot the Community Wiki...

Comment: For what is it? And why? I do not do things without reason.

Comment: (Learn to Read FAQs) It disregards reputation, and allows anyone to edit things. It is, by convention, correct to wiki subjective things, as people edit  in both sides of the conversation. I could edit posts now, but Community Wiki is normally what things like this are put into.

Comment: Also, showing attitude to people that are trying to give you valuable information is generally accepted as bad. Then again, so was the creation of the universe (D.A.)

Comment: Community Wiki is about the only reliable way not to get a subjective question closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For windows, it's hard to beat the simplicity of [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) via [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).  That being said, I much prefer the power, speed, model, and flexibility of [git](http://git-scm.com/).  git runs [on windows](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/), and would be well worth the effort it takes to learn.

Understanding the brilliance behind **git** will pay huge dividends to you as a software engineer.

**15 second Git tutorial**
Edit: It was 17 seconds.

Git started:

```
cd c:\dev\project
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
```

Edit edit edit:

```
git add file1.txt
git add file2.txt
git commit -m "Fixed up thingy."
```

Look at status:

```
git status
```

Look at history:

```
git log
```

Comment: git is harder than mathematical statistics two

Comment: yes it will pay huge dividents to me as a sofwre developer but i wasn't able to figureout what to do after i installed git. it is like programing web pages in C in DOS envirement. Not a user friendly. Windows or DOS?

Comment: Wait... you're complaining about git being hard while at the same time trying to program???  What's wrong with that picture.  Besides, git has about the simplest model out there internally, and once you understand it, git becomes vastly clear.  As I said, svn is easy.  Git is worth it.

Comment: Git. Initialize a Repo on your computer. Then put files in it. Commit to it, repeat.

Comment: Go listen to the Randal Schwartz talk on using Git.

Comment: Also, there is like a gigantically large wiki about git on StackOverflow. It took me a little, but I got it.

Comment: How I can see the differences I made in the file?

Comment: And where I can find the old versions?

Comment: Documentation and `git help` should help with that...

Comment: @ilhan: go read the docs for git.  Then try it.  Then read them again, then come back here.

Answer (score 3):

I am happy on Windows 7 with [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org) with [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) as Client. [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com) Server is a nice, point-and-click solution to setting up the Server with very little hassle.

If you're running 64 bit Windows, be sure to install the 32 bit and 64 bit versions of Tortoise alongside, so you get Shell integration from within 32 bit IDEs.

Answer (score 2):

- [Git](http://git-scm.com/)
- [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) (See [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/))
- [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) (See [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/))

All 3 are great - experiment to see what's best for you. For repository hosting, check out [Github](http://github.com), [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) (Mercurial) and [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) (svn).

Answer (score 2):

My preference is [perforce](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/downloads/index.html),  free for home use (up to 2 users), and trivial to setup if your code repository is going to be on the same machine that you write code on.  Only a little bit harder if it isn't.

It scales well enough that it's used in a lot of professional coding houses.  And it integrates with VisualStudio (I'm told, I use the command line version because I'm an old timer).

Comment: May I ask why you prefer to use a commercial product, when there are excellent free products?